# Vala: How to retrieve the names of all files in a zip archive without unzipping it?

Tags: zip, compression, gnome, vala

Is there any function in vala like `zip:list_dir` in erlang ? I found libgsf, but I don't want to decompress the zip file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `libarchive`.

```cs
void check_ok (Archive.Result r) throws IOError {
    if (r == Archive.Result.OK)
        return;
    if (r == Archive.Result.WARN)
        return;
    throw new IOError.FAILED ("libarchive returned an error");
}

int main () {

    try {
        var a = new Archive.Read ();
        check_ok (a.support_filter_all ());
        check_ok (a.support_format_all ());
        check_ok (a.open_filename ("archive.zip", 10240));

        unowned Archive.Entry entry;
        while (a.next_header (out entry) == Archive.Result.OK) {
            stdout.printf ("%s\n", entry.pathname ());
            a.read_data_skip ();
        }
    }
    catch (IOError e) {
        stderr.printf (e.message + "\n");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compile with `valac ListZip.vala --pkg libarchive --pkg gio-2.0`.

GIO is only needed for the `IOError` errordomain. In reality, you'd want to extend the `check_ok` method with some more descriptive message which operation has failed.

You can also restrict libarchive to only allow zip files. I have translated the [example from the upstream wiki](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/wiki/Examples).

Comment: GCC warned me that `archive_read_finish` is deprecated. Is there anything I can do to eliminate the warnings?

Comment: The libarchive.vapi file needs updating, the archive_read_finish function was renamed to archive_free in libarchive 3.0.2. You can report this to https://bugzilla.gnome.org/ (product Vala), so that the Vala devs can fix it.

Comment: As long as the libarchive devs don't remove archive_read_finish you can still use the vapi as is though.

Comment: Since I have all the pieces together I now added a bug report myself: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=771916