# Unzip archive on Vala

Tags: http, archive, vala, php-ziparchive

I need to take a compressed stream of zip file from the server via http, for example: `var zip_file = file.new_for_uri("http://mysi.te / archive.zip");`, and unzip into a folder on disk using Vala and preferably standard glib type libraries. Tell me how to do it.

Comment: Try libarchive https://valadoc.org/libarchive/Archive.Read.html Here is a code sample on how to use libarchive: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39675488/426242

Comment: Reading a zip file on the fly is tricky (but doable, you'd probably have to provide your own callbacks to `Archive.Read.open ()` or use a buffer in between). It would be much easier to download the zip file to a temporary location first.

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff Why you can not use Zlib or ZlibDecompressor from GIO?

Comment: A zip file is more than zlib compressed data, it has headers, possibly encryption, etc. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11611950/426242